# HistogramList with logarithmic bins?

Tags: histograms, logarithmic-scale

`HistogramList` gives the possibility to bin the elements in a list. Is it possible to have a logarithmic spacing? In an histogram I would do something like:

```
Histogram[data, "Log"]
```

I cannot find anything in the documentation...

Comment: I have updated my answer. In the documentation, it is under `Scope` and `Bin specifications` and `Height specifications`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**

```
HistogramList[data, "Log", "Probability"]
```

or for the counts:

```
HistogramList[data, "Log", "Count"]

ListPlot[Last@%]
```

**Original answer**

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200];
Histogram[data]
```

[image]

```
Histogram[data, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}]
```

[image]

```
Histogram[data, {"Log", "Sturges"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I know how to draw a logarithmic histogram, I want to know how to extract only the height of the bins with logarithmic spacings using `HistogramList`

Answer (score 6):

As you found in the documentation

```
HistogramList[data, "Log"]
```

gives you a logarithmic spacing.  But if you're going to create a histogram figure, you'll also need to adjust the heights of the histogram bars so that the area sums to 1 or sums to the sample size depending on the objective.  Here's an example:

```
(* Generate some data *)
data = RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[0, 0.5], 1000];

(* Histogram based on the log of the data *)
h = HistogramList[Log[data]];

(* Convert back to original units *)
h[[1]] = Exp[h[[1]]];

(* Generate histogram boxes *)
n = Length[data];
logH=Table[{{h[[1,i]],0},{h[[1,i]],(h[[2,i]]/n)/(h[[1,i+1]]-h[[1,i]])},
{h[[1,i+1]],(h[[2,i]]/n)/(h[[1,i+1]]-h[[1,i]])},{h[[1,i+1]],0}},{i, Length[h[[2]]]}];

(* Plot histogram and true density *)
Show[ListLinePlot[logH, PlotStyle -> {{Thin, Black}}],
 Plot[PDF[LogNormalDistribution[0, 0.5], x], {x, 0, 4}]]
```

[image: Histogram with logarithmic spacing and true density]